# tinymce-rails configuration tinymce.yml

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-rails

I'm attempting to use tinymce-rails.  I'm not certain how to setup the tinymce.yml file and the documentation doesn't really explain much.  The main issue I am having is setting up plugin configurations.  For example, how would one setup,

```
insertdate_dateformat: "%Y-%m-%d"
```

for the following plugin:

```
- insertdatetime
```

YAML is Below:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
  - insertdatetime
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure to use the version 4.0 documentation](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/tree/tinymce-4), since I am assuming you are using the latest version of the gem. Among other changes, there no longer exists an advanced theme, it's called modern.

Furthermore, you don't need to specify theme_blabla anymore. So try writing your yaml as:

```
toolbar_location: top
toolbar_align: left
statusbar_location: bottom
buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
  - insertdatetime
insertdate_dateformat: "%Y-%m-%d"
```